# What is best practice for storing local repo managed by Bitbucket Server?

Tags: security, version-control, bitbucket-server

We have Bitbucket to Manage our source for Version control and Access control. My problem is the folder where all the source files are is just sitting on the 'C' drive. Is there a better/ more secure way to do this?

Basically I don't want to make it easy to accidentally delete, or easy for someone (if unauthorized access was gained) to copy and publish our source as that could obviously be damaging to our company.

Assume the the server has a solid back up plan (following 3-2-1 methodology), and Only Domain Admins (2 people in our Organization) have local access to the files.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programming questions. While Bitbucket is a tool used by programmers, the question is not really about programming. ServerFault would be a better site for this question.

Comment: Ok cool thank you I will take it over there!